# How do i use the jQuery button class to customize a button without using theme roller?

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, uibutton, customization

I'm new to jQuery Mobile and I'm trying to figure out how exactly to customize buttons. Which classes do i have to use to access certain css properties?

For instance I know that if you want to change the background color of a button you write `.ui-btn-inner {background: white;}`. But when I do it this way it doesn't work out all the time.

I already looked on the jQuery Mobile API website but I can't seem to find anything that really explains this concept in depth.

If someone could provide me with a website or an explanation about these classes that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect the html to see what jQuery mobile buttons look like.
For a basic button, created by:

```
<a href="index.html" data-role="button">Link button</a>
```

the output looks like:

```
<a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-up-c">
    <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
        <span class="ui-btn-text">Link button</span>
    </span>
</a>
```

Create and load a custom CSS file *after* the jQuery mobile css.
Here you can override individual css classes, like

```
.ui-btn-inner {
    // !important does the trick
    background-color: #FF0 !important;
    ...
}
```

You sometimes might have to add `!important` to the css in order to override jQuery mobiles CSS. But I actually do not know when this is necessary, I just do it if it does not work without...

You can look up the structure of all elements in the jQuery mobile CSS, or, as i mentioned before, use the web inspector to see what jQuery turns your markup into.

**PS**
A more in-depth look at how the CSS works, is provided [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/theme-control-jquery-mobile.html)